# Running SAS Job through .NET

Tags: .net, sas

I have no experience of the API of SAS. I just wonder if it is possible to use any part of the API to silently run a SAS Job. I know that it is possible to just run a by starting SAS.exe process and file as argument but I want to be able to do this silently from .NET.

Any ideas of which API and method to use for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example for using ADO.net
http://support.sas.com/kb/25/276.html#
another choice is using the Integrated Object Model (IOM)
http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the appropriate licenses you can also launch a SAS job from .NET via the command line and have it run silently using SRVANY.EXE.  It will take some extra work and is a bit of a kludge but that's the only other silent alternative I'm aware of.

Comment: I should add that this was the approach that SAS themselves used when running SAS as a service back in the day...

Comment: So, I need a license to use the API? I thought license was for "server" only.